# Return string from an attribute in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, nested-loops

> I m working on nested array of objects, where I require return to be a
> specific string from an object which satisfies below conditions as
> shown in the code. But as we know forEach returns undefined, and my
> requirement is a single string as return, can any new es6 in built
> array functions be used to make it more easy? in below code value in second loop is received
> from a function, so ignore its source

```
const data = [
{ 
 column:"a" , 
 children:[
 {column: "a1", area: { defaultValue:"NY", selectedValue: "NJ"} }, 
 {column: "a2", area: { defaultValue:"IN", selectedValue: "CA"} },
 ] 
},
{ 
 column:"b" , 
 children:[
 {column: "b1", area: { defaultValue:"JP", selectedValue: "CC"} }, 
 {column: "b2", area: { defaultValue:"CA", selectedValue: "BL"} },
 ] 
},
];

const newValue = data.forEach( d => {
  if (d.column === "a" && children) {
    children.forEach(c => {
      if (c.column === value) {
       return c.area.selectedValue || c.area.defaultValue;
}
})
}
})
console.log(newValue);
```

Comment: What is the variable `value` ? `forEach()` probably isn't a good choice if you need to break out of the loop

Comment: its a value received from onChange of input field

Comment: Please include that code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be one possible way to obtain the desired objective:

```
const getNewValue = (val1 = 'a', val2 = 'a2') => {
    const foundIt = data?.find(
      d => d.column === val1
    )?.children?.find(
      c => c.column === val2
    );
  return foundIt?.area?.selectedValue ||
    foundIt?.area?.defaultValue ||
    'No matching entry found';
}
```

**Explanation**

- Use `find` to get a match on the `column`.
- Use `?.` optional-chaining to refer `children` within the matched object
- `.find` the matching value (such as `a1`, or `a2`, etc) within children
- return either the `selectedValue` or `defaultValue` or, if both are falsy, a string-constant to notify no matches.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const data = [
{ 
 column:"a" , 
 children:[
 {column: "a1", area: { defaultValue:"NY", selectedValue: "NJ"} }, 
 {column: "a2", area: { defaultValue:"IN", selectedValue: "CA"} },
 ] 
},
{ 
 column:"b" , 
 children:[
 {column: "b1", area: { defaultValue:"JP", selectedValue: "CC"} }, 
 {column: "b2", area: { defaultValue:"CA", selectedValue: "BL"} },
 ] 
},
];

const getNewValue = (val1 = 'a', val2 = 'a2') => {
    const foundIt = data?.find(
      d => d.column === val1
    )?.children?.find(
      c => c.column === val2
    );
  return foundIt?.area?.selectedValue ||
    foundIt?.area?.defaultValue ||
    'No matching entry found';
}


console.log(getNewValue());
console.log(getNewValue('a', 'a1'));
console.log(getNewValue('b', 'b1'));
console.log(getNewValue('b'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.find() should do the trick!

```
var value = "a1"

data.forEach(e => {
  if (e.column === "a")
    foundValue = e.children.find(c => 
      c.column === value
    )
})

wantedValue = foundValue.area.selectedValue || foundValue.area.defaultValue

console.log(wantedValue)
```

Comment: foundValue is declared before or directly used inside foreach?

Comment: I assumed you're using sloppy mode: so assigning to an undeclared will automatically declare it to the global object. Otherwise (strict mode) you have to declare it before the forEach().